# React Page Not Outputting Fetch Data

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, fetch-api

I've recently began studying React and am still trying to get my head around some of it's behaviours.

On the example below I am trying to obtain test data from GitHub and populate this onto a form. I managed to get promises working and the code is able to retrieve the data. However the data does not populate onto the form and I can't seem to work out where I am going wrong.

I have console logged out 'login' and the data does indeed output the correct data, however the div github-box segment does not seem to get populated with this new information.

I have also tried adding a further .then statement in the promise, in order to send the return `<Profile />;` once the fetch has been completed, but this instead outputs a blank page.

I would be extremely grateful if someone can point me in the right direction.

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Form, Card, Image, Icon } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
import './App.css';
import { GoogleMap, useLoadScript, Marker } from '@react-google-maps/api';

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [followers, setFollowers] = useState('');
  const [login, setLogin] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://api.github.com/users/example')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data.login);
        setData(data);
      });
  }, []);

  const setData = ({ name, followers }) => {
    // setName(name);
    setLogin(login);
    setFollowers(followers);
  };
  return <Profile />;

  function Profile() {
    return (

      <div>
        <h1>User Profile</h1>
        <div className="github-box">
          <Card>
            <Image
              src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/57936?v=4"
              wrapped
              ui={false}
            />
            <Card.Content>
              <Card.Header>Name:{login}</Card.Header>
              <Card.Meta>
                <span className="date">Joined in 2015</span>
              </Card.Meta>
              <Card.Description>
                Matthew is a musician living in Nashville.
              </Card.Description>
            </Card.Content>
            <Card.Content extra>
              <a>
                <Icon name="user" />
                22 Friends
              </a>
            </Card.Content>
          </Card>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: A typo?  What is this meant to accomplish?: `setLogin(login);`  Did you mean `setLogin(name);` instead?  Overall it looks like the problem isn't related to React, but that you're just defining variables with inconsistent names and confusing yourself.

Comment: Probably `setData = ({ login, followers }) => {}`. Other `login` will refer to the useState value instead, effectively setting it to itself.

Comment: Thank you! I did not add login in setData